# global-set-key settings to switch indentation?

Tags: emacs, indentation

In my own C/C++ coding, I prefer a 2-space indentation, but when I work with others, I am subject to a style guide that requires 3-space indentation. In my .emacs file (pasted below) I use custom-set-variables to set it to 2, and I can change it while running .emacs with:

```
M-x customize-set-variable
Set variable: c-basic-offset 
[integer] [radio] Set customized value for c-basic-offset to: 3
```

(except why is it custom**ize**-set-variable instead of custom-set-variable**s**? Also, it only works every other time; the first time I do it, after I enter 'c-basic-offset' it is just done (and c-basic-offset is set to 1). The next time I do it, it prompts me for what value to set it to -- what's up with that?)

So I can workaround, but that's a lot of typing, and I don't want to have to remember it.

I once searched up how to set F5 to M-x revert-buffer; What do I need to put into my .emacs file so I can have the F2 and F3 keys change c-basic-offset to 2 and 3, since the action is not a simple no-argument emacs meta command?

FYI, here is I think the relevant portion of what I currently have in my .emacs file:

```
(custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.    
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(c-basic-offset 2)
 '(fill-column 80)
 '(global-auto-revert-mode t)
 '(indent-tabs-mode nil)
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(initial-buffer-choice nil)
 '(initial-scratch-message nil))


(global-set-key [f5] 'revert-buffer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do I need to put into my .emacs file so I can have the F2 and F3
>   keys change c-basic-offset to 2 and 3, since the action is not a
>   simple no-argument emacs meta command?

```
(defun set-offset-2 ()
  (interactive)
  (setq-default c-basic-offset 2))
(defun set-offset-3 ()
  (interactive)
  (setq-default c-basic-offset 3))

(global-set-key [f2] 'set-offset-2)
(global-set-key [f3] 'set-offset-3)
```

> except why is it custom**ize**-set-variable instead of
>   custom-set-variable**s**?

Calling `customize-set-variable` prompts the user for one variable to change and then updates the list at the top of your `.emacs`. `custom-set-variables` takes that list and applies all those variables.

> Also, it only works every other time; the first time I do it, after I
>   enter 'c-basic-offset' it is just done (and c-basic-offset is set to
>   1). The next time I do it, it prompts me for what value to set it to
>   -- what's up with that?)

Strangely enough I get the same error. Not sure what's up with that.

Personally I don't use `customize-set-variable`. Instead I call the `setq-default` function explicitly. For example, the following is equivalent to what you posted earlier:

```
(custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.    
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
  )

(setq-default c-basic-offset 2)
(setq-default fill-column 80)
(setq-default global-auto-revert-mode t)
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default inhibit-startup-screen t)
(setq-default initial-buffer-choice nil)
(setq-default initial-scratch-message nil)
```

If you want to apply these changes, just put your cursor at the end of the parentheses:

```
(setq-default c-basic-offset 2)█
```

And type `C-x C-e`.

Comment: Brilliant! Your snippet into my .emacs works great! Thx also for the extra info about custom[ize]-set-variable[s]!